# If $k(\cos A + \tan B \sin A) = \tan B$, then $k= \frac{ \sin B } { \cos(A-B) }$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $$k(\cos A + \tan B \sin A) = \tan B$$

Show that $$k= \frac{ \sin B } { \cos(A-B) }$$

Comment: Hint: Rewrite $\tan B$ in terms of sine and cosine. And please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when stating problems.

Comment: Do you know a formula for cos(A-B) ?

Comment: In the future please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck. Otherwise this question islikely to be closed via community votes or just be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k=\frac{\tan B}{\cos A+\tan B\sin A}=\frac{\sin B}{\cos A\cos  B+\sin B\sin A}=\frac{\sin B}{\cos (A-B)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much